# Import PySimpleGUI no Visual Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, módulo-python

Estou com um erro quando uso o PySimpleGUI

```
         import PySimpleGUI as 
sg ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI
```

O PySimpleGUI está instalado corretamente no computador tanto que eu uso ele no Spyder. Também consigo usar o modelo random.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: Não gosto muito do Spyder e meu computador trava quando abro simultaneamente os dois

Comment: Tente verificar em qual interpretador ou versão **python** o vscode está executando, talvez nesse interpretador ou versão que ele esteja utilizando a biblioteca não esteja instalada.

Comment: está na versão 1.47, eu não sei se perdeu o suporte, mas vou testar no Visual Studio para ver se da certo.

Comment: Só enfatizando que o vscode mostra a versão do python e o interpretador que ele está utilizando no canto inferior esquerdo da tela, ao clickar nele vc irá ver todas as versões de python instaladas na sua máquina e vc pode alterar para a versão certa que vc instalou o pacote ou vc pode instalar o pacote na versão que vscode está utilizando!

Comment: Consegui resolvendo assim: Dei um Ctrl+Shift+P depois Select Interpreter e coloquei o Python na versão 3.7 (conda). Pelo visto a 3.8 não oferece suporte pro PySimpleGUI.

Answer (score -1):

Man, creio que você tenha que instalá-lo antes de usar nessa IDE. Lembre-se que esse código que vou passar só vai funcionar se você tiver o Python instalado em seu computador.

Abra o PowerShell,

```
pip install pysimplegui
ou
pip3 install pysimplegui
```

Diferentemente do googlecolab ou jupyter que tu usa online, em IDE's que rodam na sua máquina como VSCode, Spyder etc é preciso instala-lo.

Comment: Consegui resolvendo assim: Dei um Ctrl+Shift+P depois Select Interpreter e coloquei o Python na versão 3.7 (conda). Pelo visto a 3.8 não oferece suporte pro PySimpleGUI. Mas brigadão pela resposta

Comment: O jupyter não é utilizado online. Apenas roda no navegador

Answer (score -2):

Recentemente tive esse problema usando Python 3.9. Depois de muito pesquisar e não achar nada, resolvi procurar na minha máquina a solução. Resolvi da seguinte forma:
Ao executar o comando pip3 install PySimpleGUI, recebia a confirmação da instalação, e resolvi procurar a pasta de instalação da PySimpleGUI. Encontrei neste caminho:
'C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)'
Este é o caminho onde está instalado o pacote 'pip'
Observei que a biblioteca Tkinter estava em outro caminho: 'C:\Users\Kito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib'

Copiei os arquivos de instalação do PySimpleGUI que estava no primeiro caminho e colei no mesmo caminho que estava o Tkinter e funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]